# How to sort by a specific criteria the top X documents already sorted with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

It's a bit hard for me to formulate this question. The thing is, I need to get the 100 best rated documents and then sort the result by another criteria.

I'm a beginner with mongodb and I naively tried something like:

```
db.myCollection
  .find()                                 // get all the data
  .sort({ "statistics.average": -1 })     // sort by rating
  .limit(100)                             // get the 100 best rated
  .sort({ "statistics.foobar": -1 })      // sort the result by the second criteria
```

But it doesn't work and it looks like the last sort is done on all the data.

How to properly create a query to fit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo applies the sort before limiting the results regardless of the order you call sort and limit on the cursor but using the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method will give the expected result.

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "statistics.average": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 100 }, 
    { "$sort": { "statistics.foobar": -1 } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.myCollection
  .find()                                 // get all the data
  .sort({ "statistics.average": -1 ,"statistics.foobar": -1 })     // sort by rating followed by foobar
  .limit(100) // get the 100 best rated
```